# Not able to list users based on tag using JavaScript SDK in QuickBlox

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am trying list users based on tag, I have users added in quickblox with two tags : `public, private`. I am using JavaScript SDK demo.

```
QB.users.listUsers({page: usersStorage.currentPage, per_page: '10'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(result);

      mergeUsers(result.items);

      callback(result.items);

      $("#load-users").delay(100).fadeOut(500);

      usersStorage.totalEntries = result.total_entries;
      usersStorage.retrievedCount = usersStorage.retrievedCount + result.items.length;
    }
  });
```

Can anyone tell me how can I load users with private tag only?

I have tried using `QB.users.get` function with argument `{tags : 'private'}` but while it's going to call `api.quickblox.com` for load user's list, it's giving `404 not found` response code. While same code is working with users demo of JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk/blob/gh-pages/samples/users/main.js#L185

```
var params = {tags: "public"};

QB.users.listUsers(params, function(err, result){
...
})
```

More info on Users API is here https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-users-javascript

Comment: I have used 
var params = {tags: ["public"]};   QB.users.get(params, function(err, result){ if (result) {  console.warn(result);  } });   
but I am getting 404 (Not Found) from QuickBlox api. What's the issue? @Igor

Comment: Maybe yo do not have users with tag 'public' ?

Comment: I don't know what was the issue behind this, but it's working now. strange